# iOS : Is this need to release

Tags: ios, release

I am using Instruments to check leak memory of my app and show me this:
[image]

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChangeAccountCellViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```

Should I release this "nib"? Thank you in advance !

Comment: if by release, you mean to delete its handle to release the memory, then yes. you should always do that

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm fairly certain that by release he means sending `release` to the instance. And iOS has no such concept as deleting the handle to an object.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: @ColeJohnson I can neither see the word `delete` nor `handle` in this document...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory management in Objective-C is as follows: if you create an object with `alloc`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, you are in charge of calling `release` on it at the appropriate time.  Otherwise, you can be secure in the knowledge that it is being handled properly elsewhere.

As your nib was not created with any of the above methods, no, you should not release it.

Comment: No problem!  Good luck with your continuing development :)